# Not visible buttons on Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: support, meta

[image: Button]

Buttons <kbd>Questions</kbd>, <kbd>Tags</kbd>, <kbd>Users</kbd> and others become visible only when they hover the mouse cursor. I think it is a bug, not so intended.

Windows XP SP3, Firefox 46.0.1 and Chrome 48.0.2564.116

Comment: No repro on Windows 64 bit, Firefox 46.0.1.

Comment: Voting to reopen based on OP self answer, it was some fancy browser add-on breaking stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled [Ad Muncher](https://www.admuncher.com/), problem solved.

[image: Ad Muncher]